# msie strange div formatting (among other issues) what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8

On the page http://listtree.appspot.com/about/bEcPYABxI$6UeBDHzASwlA 
if I scroll to the bottom using MSIE 8 the left hand side yellow div borders to a weird jumping up and down dance -- what am I doing wrong?  I have similar pages where this isn't happening and the "developers tools" interface seems happy with the html.

Also, on the same page, why is MSIE silently ignoring my javascipt:... links? Again, I have other pages using the same techniques that seem to be working fine unde MSIE, and of course I see no problems in either firefox or safari whereever I've tried it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the issues you're describing in IE8 on Windows 7.

Comment: I get different anomalies on different systems, but I haven't seen it right yet -- on Vista if I scroll up then down the lines get broken up.  I'm wondering if IE doesn't like div boxes with visible borders only along the left...

Answer (score 0):

I ran IE 8 on Windows XP through browser sandbox with no problems. Must be whatever you are using to render it or OS.

Answer (score 0):

I give up.

I fixed the problem by switching from using DIV's to using TABLE's.

And to hell with the kittens

[alt text http://aaron.oirt.rutgers.edu/kitten.jpg](http://aaron.oirt.rutgers.edu/kitten.jpg)

here is how it looks now: http://listtree.appspot.com/...